# Falha no vagrant up puphpet/ubuntu1604-x64

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, windows-10

Sepre que inicio o vagrant para iniciar um projeto acontece esse erro:

> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>   ==> default: Box 'puphpet/ubuntu1604-x64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
>       default: Box Provider: virtualbox
>       default: Box Version: >= 0 The box 'puphpet/ubuntu1604-x64' could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this
>   is a private box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in
>   via `vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
>   URL and error message are shown below:
>
> URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puphpet/ubuntu1604-x64"] Error: The
>   requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

Eu já havia utilizado essa box antes, mas agora esta acontecendo esse erro e não é só com essa box é com todas as box que tento iniciar em novo projeto.

Alguém saberia o que pode ser!

Comment: Você usa proxy?

Comment: Não utilizo proxy!